# how to display categories in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is simple but I don't fully understand about the concept. I have categories table in database, so I want to create a page for each records in my categories table

I already display the records in my database in view, but I have no idea how to set `href`  to each record.

My controller

```
 public function index(){
     $this->load->model('Model_Category');
     $data['row2']= $this->Model_Category->get_category();
     $this->load->view('view_page.php',$data);
 }
```

My view

```
 <div class="row mb-4">
   <div class="items mr-2 ml-2">
     <?php foreach ($row2->result() as $key=>$data) : ?>
       <a class="text-light listcategory" href="#"><span><?=$data->name_cat?></span></a>    
     <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>    
 </div>
```

so, how to create a page for all my records?

Comment: if your categories data have some kind of slug on it, you could display it on your `href`, like `href="<?php echo $data->slug_cat ?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really subjective, it depends on how you want to handle your URIs. But for a simple option, the controller would look like this

```
class Categories extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // this makes working with urls easier
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('Model_Category');
        $data['row2']= $this->Model_Category->get_category();
        $this->load->view('view_page.php',$data);
    }

    // Below, handle the logic for displaying a single category
    public function details($slug) {
        $this->load->model('Model_Category');
        $data['row2']= $this->Model_Category->get_category_by_slug($slug);
        $this->load->view('view_details_page.php', $data);
    }

}
```

In your view, defined the href like this:
I am using a slug in this snippet but you can use anything that will uniquely identify your category rows in your database.

```
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="items mr-2 ml-2"> 
        <?php foreach ($row2->result() as $key => $data) : ?>
        <a class="text-light listcategory" href="<?= site_url('category/details/'.$data->slug) ?>">
            <span><?= $data->name_cat ?></span>
        </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    /div>
</div>
```

Finally, In your model, query the single category row

```
public function get_category_by_slug($slug) {
    $this->db->select('column1, column2, column3');
    $this->db->from('categories_table');
    $this->db->where('unique_column', $sulg);

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: public function details($slug) {
        $this->load->model('Model_Category');
        $data['row2']= $this->Model_Category->get_category_by_slug($slug);
        $this->load->view('view_details_page.php', $data);
    }

ok i understand a little bit, but i am wondering about this function .. so it will bring up products in each of these categories, right?
sorry if my question is too odd.. thanks for your answer

Comment: This is an example function to show you how to display individual categories. The idea is to have a unique way to identify a category (by its id or maybe a slug). Then using this unique identifier, query the categories table to return data on that category. And finally display it on the browser.

Comment: CodeIgniter has excellent documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: ok thanks for your answer yesigye.  i will learn the documentation first